# Permuation GRE question

Tags: combinatorics

[image]

SO for this one there are positions p1,p2,p3,p4,p5 . . . the square must be in p5 and the clove can only be in one position ? I'm so confused with this one . . . i can't plug it in to n!/((n-r)!r!) or anything .

Comment: I assume it means "$\clubsuit$ can only be used once in each arrangement"?

Comment: Just parsing this is confusing (I am a native English speaker!).

Comment: The last position is essentially irrelevant. Split it in to two possibilities: no clubs and one club.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one $3$-symbol arrangement allowed using the first symbol, the club.
Then, for the last symbol in the third place, you can choose any of the remaining three symbols for the first place and any of the same three symbols for the second place. This gives $3 \times 3 = 9$ arrangements, and, counting the first possibility, gives us a total of $10$ arrangements.

Answer (score 3):

The real challenge with this problem is parsing the question. God forbid if you take the GRE and English is not your strong suit. Obviously some linguistic pervert sets the questions.

Since $\square$ appears at the end in all, we are basically looking at two symbol arrangements. 
Since $\clubsuit$ can only be used in one arrangement, we can ignore it and add $1$ later.

Then we have $3$ other symbols, so we have $3^2$ arrangements with these.

So the total is $3^2+1 = 10$.

Comment: Nice explanation, and I agree with parsing the question haha. +1

Comment: @Joe: Just letting off steam as I try to parse my upcoming health insurance options :-).